Displaying antialiasing in Gimp
I am trying to fill a selected (often disconnected) area in Gimp with a solid color without any antialising effect. I though I succeeded in this up to the point I manually selected an area (apparently with color continuity not agreeing with the gimp one).
The following image contains 2 selections. The upper one is selected using the Fuzzy select tool and the second one the Free select tool.

The following image is the result after pressing Del button (which I think is just a shortcut for painting with the background color)

Apparently the second selection contains antialiasing pixels which I do not want to appear. The same result occurs when I just use Bucket fill tool. (Antialiasing pixels appear I mean).
Is there a way to disable this behaviour in gimp?
